# Implications of has_many :segments, :order => 'position ASC'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In a Rails 2.3.5 project I found this line of code in a model:

```
class Foo
  has_many :segments, :class_name => 'FooSegment', :order => 'position ASC'
end
```

The underlying table of FooSegment has an integer attribute position. And as one might guess, the many FooSegments belonging to a Foo have positions 1, 2, 3...

So can I assume that ActiveRecord always updates this position attribute behind the scenes? In particular: having a Foo with id=11, having 5 FooSegments. Is it save to assume that they always have positions 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and keep this order if a FooSegment is updated?

Thanks, Philip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not functionality that AR has built-in. However, the project may be using the [acts_as_list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) gem or something similar to provide this functionality. By default it uses a column named `position` and then keeps it up-to-date when other records change.